# Find one string in a file and replace its match in another file

Tags: awk, solaris, ksh, replace

I'm trying to replace a string in one file with its matched alias in another file.

For example I want to match the first field in each line of File A and substitute it with what it equals in File B.

I'm not sure how to tackle that? Would it be awk with a for loop or something?

Trying to script this in Solaris...

File A

> ```
> KVHPOJNOTES KVHPOJNOTESSERVER C_POJ_NOTES_C1D63EN
> KVHPOJNOTES KVHPOJNOTESSERVER C_POJ_NOTES_C99HXEN
> KVHNOTESIDANAPC KVHPOJANAPC C_POJ_NOTES_START_ANAPC
> KVHNOTESIDANAPC KVHPOJANAPC C_POJ_NOTES_STOP_ANAPC
> KVHNOTESIDANAPD KVHPOJANAPD C_POJ_NOTES_START_ANAPD
> ```

File B

> ```
>     KVHNOTESIDAHMLB=ahml02 
>     KVHNOTESIDAHUBA=ahub01
>     KVHNOTESIDALMLD=alml02
>     KVHNOTESIDANAPC=anap02
>     KVHNOTESIDANAPD=anap04
>     KVHNOTESIDALMLF=alml06
> ```

I was thinking it would be something along the lines of

```
for i in `cat "File A"`
do
grep $1 "File B" | awk ' { print $3 } '
done
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is you expected output - the description is not very clear, plus your code has some issues, so it is hard to guess what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using AWK:

```
awk '{ if(NR != FNR) { if(map[$1]) $1=map[$1];print } 
     else { split($0,a,"=");map[a[1]]=a[2];}}' FileB FileA
```